# Align <div> with display inline or inline-block without width

Tags: html, css, alignment

In my project I have a row with "User name", "Company phone" and "Logo". I was asked to align company phone in the middle between "Logo" and "User name". I have a problem with this, because user name can be between 5 and 30 characters long, so I can't give it fixed width. The company phone is image (NOT TEXT). 
[image: Demo for design]

[image: Demo for design]

Please help! I can't find anything that works for my example. Thanks.

Comment: Make each of these components have the same %-width value. Say, they all have a width of 33%. Then the text inside each of them will not intervene with the rest of the layout. This is, of course, a suggestion based on not knowing how you wrote the whole thing :)

Comment: This is exactly my problem! When I make each <div> with width="33%", The phone doesn't move on user name length change.

Comment: Aah, you mean it SHOULD look like the second image? I am sorry, it seems I didn't understand it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.phone {
  flex-grow: 1; /* Grow to fill avilable space */
  text-align: center; /* Center contents */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
  <div class="phone">1-999-999-999</div>
  <div class="name">User name</div>
  <div class="exit">Exit</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
  <div class="phone">1-999-999-999</div>
  <div class="name">Very long user name for this demo</div>
  <div class="exit">Exit</div>
</div>
```